# React Native HOC's and duplicate lifecycle method functions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

So I just discovered HOC's (Higher Order Functions) yesterday and they are pretty sweet. In my development I do use lifecycle methods like componentDidUpdate fairly frequently. I have found that I would like to use many HOCs for one wrapper component like so:

```
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    RefreshHOC(FeedScreen),
    LoggedInHOC(FeedScreen)
)(FeedScreen)
```

I have noticed that if I have the same lifecycle (say componentDidUpdate) method in the WrapperComponent and one of the HOCs both lifecycle methods work. The problem arises when I have a Wrapper Component that has a lifecycle method then two or more HOC's also have the same lifecycle method, then only the first HOC's lifecycle method runs (in the above example componentDidUpdate runs in RefershHOC but not in LoggedInHOC).

Is there a better way to design this pattern? Am I just getting some syntax incorrect? Should I just have 1 HOC for each special lifecycle method that I want to group logic?

**Edit**

Here is some example code that I think is sufficient enough:

```
class FeedScreen extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        let {appbase, auth, dispatch} = this.props
        console.log('fire')
    }

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    info: state.info,
    auth: state.auth,
    appbase: state.appbase
})
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    LoggedInHOC(FeedScreen),
    LoggedInHOC2(FeedScreen)
)(FeedScreen)

export const LoggedInHOC = WrapperComponent => props => class 
    ViewWithPropChanges extends Component {
      componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log('fire LIHOC')
      }

      render(){
        return (<WrapperComponent {...this.props}/>)
      }
 }
}

export const LoggedInHOC2 = WrapperComponent => props => class ViewWithPropChanges extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
       console.log('fire LIHOC2')
    }

render(){
        return (<WrapperComponent {...this.props}/>)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code that can be tested to illustrate your point ?

Comment: Sorry @Saraband I had a tough deadline I had to get to, I updated with some minimal code to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Some of your code seems a bit strange to me:

```
export const LoggedInHOC = WrapperComponent => props => class

// Later
export default compose(
  LoggedInHOC(FeedScreen)
)(FeedScreen)
```

`LoggedInHOC` here is a function that takes a component and returns a function that returns a component when it should probably be only a function that takes a component and returns a component.

I'm going to assume that the role your `LoggedInHOC` is to check whether a user is connected somehow, display the wrapped component if that's the case and redirect the user/show a login form otherwise.

You could write it like that:

```
export const LoggedInHOC = Component => class extends React.Component {
  render () {
    // Check if the user is connected
    if (connected) {
      return (
        <Component
          {...this.props}
          />
      );
    }

    return <p>User not connected</p>;
  }
};
```

And you would wrap your component like that

```
export default LoggedInHOC(Component);

// Or if you want to chain multiple hocs:
export default compose(
  LoggedInHOC,
  AnotherHOC
)(Component);
```

Now back to your original question about chaining multiple HOCs and `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle. I'm not sure what is the exact problem in your case, but writting:

```
export default compose(
  HOC1,
  HOC2
)(Component);
```

is equivalent to `HOC1(HOC2(Component))`. So in term of composition you have:

```
HOC1
  HOC2
    Component
```

And you have to keep in mind that when your `HOC1` wrapper is updated, that will trigger an update in your `HOC2` and in your `Component` but if you update your `HOC2`, that will not trigger an update to your `HOC1`.

[I made a example codepen that displays a component wrapped in multiple HOCs each implementing a `componentDidUpdate` hook](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXZWJQ?editors=0011)

Comment: Yea I think it may have something to do with componentDidUpdate specifically? Does componentDidUpdate work in your above example?

Comment: I edited my answer above (check the codepen for a working example)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer that, your way of making it into a function that takes a component and returns a component (not the convoluted thing I had before) does seem to give me the ability to use componentDidUpdate across multiple HOCs.